# Vue | How to emit all to parent

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

Is there a way in Vue to emit all emitters to parent listening?

For example turn that code:

```html
<DetailsPages
  v-if="$route.hash === '#details_pages'"
  v-on:next="$emit('next')"
  v-on:need-to-save="save => $emit('need-to-save', save)"
  v-on:goto-step="step => $emit('goto-step', step)"
/>
<DetailsContact
  v-if="$route.hash === '#details_contact'"
  v-on:next="$emit('next')"
  v-on:need-to-save="save => $emit('need-to-save', save)"
  v-on:goto-step="step => $emit('goto-step', step)"
/>
<DetailsInfo
  v-if="$route.hash === '#details_info'"
  v-on:next="$emit('next')"
  v-on:need-to-save="save => $emit('need-to-save', save)"
  v-on:goto-step="step => $emit('goto-step', step)"
/>
```

to something like this:

```
<DetailsPages v-if="$route.hash === '#details_pages'" v-on:emit="$emit" />
<DetailsContact v-if="$route.hash === '#details_contact'" v-on:emit="$emit" />
<DetailsInfo v-if="$route.hash === '#details_info'" v-on:emit="$emit" />
```

Comment: Please, don't spam tags. Is it 2 or 3? Things are made differently there.

Comment: sorry, this specific project is on vue2 but I also have projects on vue 3 so both answers are relevant even if it's possible only in one version

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Vue 2 you can apply all parent listeners to the child component like that:

```js
<DetailsPages v-on="$listeners" />
```

Vue 3 [removed](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/listeners-removed.html) $listeners by merging them into $attrs. You can still achieve what you want like this:

```js
<DetailsPages v-bind="$attrs" />
```

However, take into account that while $attrs contains $listeners, it also includes other things